# How to dump a YAML with an int with leading zeros?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I need to dump an integer with leading zeros, but not as a string.
I can dump it like a string in this way:

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

data = {'identifier': '001'}

yaml = YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

The result is:

```
identifier: '001'
```

I do not need to dump as a string, but as a number.
I need a result like:

```
identifier: 001
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: I am sorry, but an int with leading zeros does not really makes sense. As (as int) `01` is the very same as `1`, they will be represented the same way (except when given as *strings*): `1`. It is true on any system I know that has the notion of what an integer is, whatever the language.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I mean I need to dump the data like an integer but with leading zeros.

Comment: Then you cannot rely on a *standard* YAML library. But you can perfectly write a text file having the format you want by using lower level `print` function and/or `format` method.

Comment: @BrianSidebotham Of course you can

Comment: @Duncan it is not entirely clear from your example if you want to specify `'001'` and have it automatically be converted, or would prefer to specify this explicitly. Both are trivially done using my answer, the former by recursively walking over your datastructure searching for strings with leading zeros that consists only of numbers. The other by using the last line of my answer.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You can trivially do that with `ruamel.yaml` and with the appropriate representer you can do that with PyYAML as well. If those two are non-standard libraries, what would you consider a standard library?

Comment: @Anthon Well done. Good job. I cannot imagine why on earth that's required, but it doesn't matter - well done making it possible for someone. :+1:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to do if you need to check if a particular output can be generated is
trying to round-trip the result:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
identifier: 001
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['another'] = double_o_one = data['identifier']
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
identifier: 001
another: 001
```

So this proves this can be done programmatically, and if worst comes to worst and
you cannot figure out how to make the `double_o_one` from scratch, you can
load it from a string.

If you investigate a bit more and have a look at the source of `scalarint.py`:

```py
print(type(double_o_one))
print(double_o_one.__dict__)
print()

data['james'] = double_o_seven = ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt(7, width=3)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

and that gives:

```
<class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt'>
{'_width': 3, '_underscore': None}

identifier: 001
another: 001
james: 007
```

So if you start out with a string `x = '001'`, you do `x = ScalarInt(int(x), len(x))`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = {'identifier': 0o001}
```

This will convert to an integer. But , not in the format you specified.